# How to create Set in groovy script for SOAP ui to be able to reuse it in my test cases?

Tags: web-services, testing, groovy, soapui

I am testing object coverage for certain reporting solution. I have hundreds of reports and I need to see if set of objects used in those reports covers the set of all possible objects. I figured out that I could use set collection to store distinct object names and then handle it in some way. As I use free version of SOAPui for time being, structure of my test is first invoking method to get XML view of single report, then use Groovy Script to append found object names into a csv file (File append method). However I would like to append those object after I get rid of duplicates. So suitable solution would be a Set variable where I could store object names from all reports and in last step store this set in a file.

How to create such reusable collection? Is there any other way I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just declare a set like below

```
def setOfNames = [] as Set
// set manipulation
setOfNames.add("a")
//
```

Or just declare a list first, manipulate it, then finally make a set out of it

```
def listOfNames = []
// list manipulation
def setOfNames = listOfNames as Set
```

Refer http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections for more details